# Trying to get Javascript, CSS, and HTML code written in JSfiddle to run in Github Pagse

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, jsfiddle

I have written HTML, CSS, and Javasript code in JSfiddle. I am trying to upload that code to github and have it run on github pages. The HTML and CSS part seem to run fine but none of the Javascript functions are working. I am unsure what to do to fix this.

GitHub [repository](https://github.com/GeorgeRidgeway/testing-site) and [site](https://georgeridgeway.github.io/testing-site/)

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

I tried ensuring the JavaScript file was called correctly and tried using `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {});`.

```js
let countElStrikes = document.getElementById("count-el-strikes")

let countElBalls = document.getElementById("count-el-balls")

let countElBatter = document.getElementById("count-el-batter")

let countElResult = document.getElementById("count-el-previous")

let countStrikes = 0

let countBalls = 0

let count = 0


function strikes() {
  if (countElBatter.innerText !== "Walk") {
    countStrikes += 1
    countElStrikes.innerText = countStrikes
    console.log(countElStrikes.innerText)
  }
  if (countStrikes == 3) {
    countElBatter.innerText = "Out"
    console.log("Out")
  }
  if (countStrikes >= 4) {
    countStrikes = 0;
    countBalls = 0;
    document.getElementById("count-el-strikes").innerHTML = countStrikes;
    document.getElementById("count-el-balls").innerHTML = countBalls;
    countElBatter.innerText = ""
    console.log("Out")
  }
}

function balls() {
  if (countElBatter.innerText !== "Out") {
    countBalls += 1;
    countElBalls.innerText = countBalls
    console.log(countElBalls.innerText)
  }
  if (countBalls == 4) {
    countElBatter.innerText = "Walk"
    console.log("Walk")
  }
  if (countBalls >= 5) {
    countStrikes = 0;
    countBalls = 0;
    document.getElementById("count-el-strikes").innerHTML = countStrikes;
    document.getElementById("count-el-balls").innerHTML = countBalls;
    countElBatter.innerText = ""
    console.log("Out")
  }
}

function save() {
  result = countElBatter.innerText
  if (result == "Walk" || result == "Out") {
    countElResult.textContent += result + " - "
    countStrikes = 0;
    countBalls = 0;
    document.getElementById("count-el-strikes").innerHTML = countStrikes;
    document.getElementById("count-el-balls").innerHTML = countBalls;
    countElBatter.innerText = ""
    console.log("Out")
  }
}


function reset() {
  countStrikes = 0;
  countBalls = 0;
  countElResult.innerText = " ";
  document.getElementById("count-el-strikes").innerHTML = countStrikes;
  document.getElementById("count-el-balls").innerHTML = countBalls;
  countElBatter.innerText = ""
  console.log("Out")
}
```

```css
button {
  border: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#background-image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 612px;
  width: 612px;
}

#baseball-content {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#result-content {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#strikes-btn {
  background: darkblue;
}

#strikes-btn:active {
  background-color: black;
  /* Change this color to the desired pressed color */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#balls-btn {
  background: darkblue;
}

#balls-btn:active {
  background-color: black;
  /* Change this color to the desired pressed color */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#save-btn {
  background: darkblue;
}

#save-btn:active {
  background-color: black;
  /* Change this color to the desired pressed color */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#reset-btn {
  background: darkblue;
}

#reset-btn:active {
  background-color: black;
  /* Change this color to the desired pressed color */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="index.js"></script>

</head>
<center>

  <body style="margin:10%;">
    <div id="background-image" style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1389744315/vector/vector-baseball-field-baseball-diamond-baseball-stadium-stock-illustration.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=36T0kBfFAWRRkj4OMAzLYdOX0ulMKbjIh18Q3wZzs48=')">

      <h1 style="font-size:30pt;">Pitch Counter</h1>
      <br>

      <div id="baseball-content">
        <h2 style=' margin:0;'>Strikes: <span id="count-el-strikes"></span></h2>
        <h2 style=' margin:0;'>Balls: <span id="count-el-balls"></span></h2>
        <h2 style=' margin:0;'>Batter: <span id="count-el-batter"></span></h2>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button id="strikes-btn" onclick="strikes()">Strikes</button>
      <button id="balls-btn" onclick="balls()">Balls</button>
      <br>
      <!-- <button id="reset-btn" onclick="reset()">Reset Count</button> -->
      <button id="save-btn" onclick="save()">Save and Reset Count</button>
      <button id="reset-btn" onclick="reset()">Reset Results</button>
      <br>
      <h2 id="result-content" style="font-size:18pt;">Previous Result: <span id="count-el-previous"></span></h2>


    </div>

  </body>
</center>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a console error which points you right to the problem. An ID in your script doesn't exist in the page markup.

Comment: Note that the code you provided doesn't match what's in the page. That's a problem for us trying to help you. Also, the [`center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) element is deprecated. Don't use it. It's also outside the body element, which is invalid.